# Monit state file version warning

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monit

I am running Monit version `5.17.1` on Ubuntu `14.04`. At times, I 
see that Monit has logged the following:

```
[PST Nov 14 15:42:40] warning  : State file '/var/lib/monit/state': incompatible version 2
```

And after this, my services (that are monitored by Monit) restart.
What can cause this to happen? Is this just file corruption ?
(I have not upgraded or changed Monit version)

Let's say that this occurred, is there some way in Monit to check/correct
(maybe delete and recreate *state* file) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just delete this file. It is used to store the current state of monit. Documentation states:

> *~/.monit.state* Monit saves its state to this file and utilises information found in this file to recover from a crash. This is a binary file and its content is only of interest to monit.

So you'll loose the ability to act to the entities last state **for one monit circle**, but everything else should work fine. Just the `SET ONREBOOT` directive will stop working with `LASTSTATE` **for one time/cycle**.

Comment: I can delete this file _after_ I see some issue, but do you suggest that this file be removed each time after a reboot? what is the version mismatch error mean ?

Comment: **No, I totally do not recommend to delete this file at all...** But since this error seems to point to any kind of corruption to this file, I think this will help you out without the loss of any data. I personally never encountered this problem while using Monit on > 20 hosts.